# How to make list of static options in fragment?

Tags: android, android-view

I need to create list of some static options in fragment. There is screen with options:

[image: sample]

I want to make something like that. What should I use for more efficient way?

Comment: Hi. Have you checked this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)? You can create a list of Strings and provide it to a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's visually similar to the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), but as explained by Mehmed, it's just de RecyclerView, or even few items in a vertical LinearLayout